# is there a way in c++ to cast a pointer to the real type it points to?

Tags: c++, casting, typeid

**Edited. see below.**

Consider the following situation -
I have a base class and some derived ones :

```
class B {...[virtual...]...};

class D1 : public B {...};

class D2 : public B {...};
```

and I have a function that suppose to behave differently on each of them (implement-wise. conceptually, they all do the same thing). 
now, I would of course implement an auxiliary function for each :

```
void f_aux (B * b);
void f_aux (D1 * d1);
void f_aux (D2 * d2);
```

and then I can implement the main function by doing something like this :

```
void f (B * bd1d2) {
       if (typeid(bd1d2) == typeid(B*)  { f_aux((B*)bd1d2);  }
  else if (typeid(bd1d2) == typeid(D1*) { f_aux((D1*)bd1d2); }
  else if (typeid(bd1d2) == typeid(D2*) { f_aux((D2*)bd1d2); }
}
```

now, my question is - can I do this in a general way, meaning something like :

```
void f (B * bd1d2) {
       f_aux(CAST_TO_REAL_TYPE(bd1d2));
}
```

I tried using typeid directly which of course failed.
I tried searching that online and nothing came up..

so, Is there a way of doing it? and if there isn't, than why?

many thanks..

**Edit :**

I tried to simplify the problem, and it seems that I've done the opposite..
Let me try again :
In the real settings, I have 3 classes : Line, Ray and Segment, and I'd like another class (a Graph-Edge) to hold a general pointer to an object any of the types - meaning, it has a field that can be either Line Ray or Segment.
Now, I'd like to have the option to get an intersection point of 2 Graph-Edges, or of a Graph-Edge with a given Line/Ray/Segment without dealing with the question of "what kind of an edge is this?" on none of the two.
I would also like to have my Geometry classes as generic as possible, even if some of the functionality is not necessary in Graph-Edges..
So I made a super-class : LinearObject, with a virtual getCut(LinearObject & lo) function, and followed the answers below, and the best I've got so far is this :

```
class Line;
class Segment;

class LinearObject {
public :
    virtual void getCut(LinearObject * lo) { printf("lo->lo\n"); }
private :
    virtual void getCut_aux(Line * l) = 0;
    virtual void getCut_aux(Segment * s) = 0;

friend class Line;  friend class Segment;
};

class Line : public LinearObject {
public :
    void getCut(LinearObject * lo) { printf("l->lo\n"); lo->getCut_aux(this); }
private :
    void getCut_aux(Line * l) { printf("l->l\n"); }
    void getCut_aux(Segment * s) { printf("l->s\n"); }
};

class Segment : public LinearObject  {
public :
    void getCut(LinearObject * lo) {
        printf("s->lo\n");
        lo->getCut_aux(this);
    }
private :
    void getCut_aux(Line * l) { printf("s->l\n"); }
    void getCut_aux(Segment * s) { printf("s->s\n"); }
};

int main() {
    Line l; Segment s;
    LinearObject *lop = &l, *lop2 = &s;
    lop->getCut(lop2);
    s.getCut(&l);
    return 0;
}
```

It works, but, can I do any better (Eleganltly) ?

Comment: Do you have to implement the `f_aux` function outside the class?

Comment: @Holt
not exactly. I'll post a more detailed answer as a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Edit after you question edit, hope I understand everything you want...

```
#include <cstdio>

class Line;
class Segment;

class LinearObject {
protected :
    virtual void getCut_aux(LinearObject *) { printf("LinearObject->getCut_aux\n") ; }

    friend class LinearObject_ ;
};

class LinearObject_ : public LinearObject {
public:
    void getCut (LinearObject * lo) { printf("getCut()\n"); lo->getCut_aux(this) ; }
};

class Line : public LinearObject_ {
protected :
    virtual void getCut_aux(LinearObject *) { printf("Line->getCut_aux\n") ; }

};

class Segment : public LinearObject_  {
protected:
    virtual void getCut_aux(LinearObject *) { printf("Segment->getCut_aux\n") ; }
};

int main() {
    Line l; Segment s;
    LinearObject *lop = &l, *lop2 = &s;
    l.getCut(lop2);
    s.getCut(&l); 
    return 0;
}
```

**End of edit.**

If you can implement `f_aux` inside the class, just take advantage of polymorphism:

```
class B {
    /* ...[virtual...]... */
    virtual void f_aux () { /* ... */ } 
};

class D1 : public B {
    /* ... */
    virtual void f_aux () { /* ... */ } 
};

class D2 : public B {
    /* ... */
    virtual void f_aux () { /* ... */ } 
};
```

Then just do:

```
void f (B * bd1d2) {
    bd1d2->f_aux () ; // Will call the correct function depending on what bd1d2 points to
}
```

**Edit:** To answer your comment, if you want to have something like `d->f_aux(b)` just add an intermediate class `D`:

```
class D {
    void f (B *b) { b->f_aux(this) ; }
};

class D1 : public B, public D { /* ... */ };

B  *pdb = new B (), *pd3 = new D3 () ;
D1 *pd1 = new D1 () ;
D2 *pd2 = new D2 () ;
pd1->f(b) ;
pd2->f(pd3) ;
```

Comment: it was actually a simplification of the real situation. In the real problem I want to implement a binary function between 2 instances of drivatives of B. the usage would be something like : p1->f(p2), where each of p1,p2 can point to D1, D2, D3, etc. but p1, p2 will always be defined as B*. I guess I could follow your advise and do something like : 
void D#::f(B* b) { return b->f_aux(this); }, right?
but I did want something more general and less hacky...

Comment: @elad: I think the solution is to split `f_aux` to two parts: the first parameter part and the second parameter part.

Comment: @elad Why is defining `f` inside the class hacky?

Comment: @Holt, because it makes me declare "unnecessary" pure virtual aux functions in the base class, one for each derived class, and in general I wished that c++ would also know to dynamically choose between functions by the real type of the pointer/reference arguments, or at leat supply a clean option to force such an action. 
well, it is slightly better than if-else on typeid. thanks again..

Comment: @Dani, I did not understand you.. the function f is about a relation between 2 objects. how would I split it?

Comment: @elad: That depends on what the function does

Comment: @elad If you look at my edit, there is no 'unnecessary' pure virtual functions. If my edited post does not match your requirement, you should edit your question and add the necessary information.

Comment: @Holt, I did not understand the D class method. I tried, and could not get it to work. you can see my edit in the main question and treat it in the new (original) settings. thanks again.

Comment: @elad I don't understand why your `getCut_aux` method is virtual in `LinearObject` and `getCut` isn't? With your explanation, I thought it was the opposite.

Comment: @elad I meant `virtual pure`, not only virtual.

Comment: @Holt, well, they both are. `getCut` needs to be virtual in order to have `this` argument of the right type when "switching" the order of arguments, and all `getCut_aux` functions need to be virtual to actually make the call to it (to have it compiled). am I wrong? and like I asked - can I do better?

Comment: @elad In your first post, you were able to call `f_aux` with `B*` which is not possible in your edit because `getCut_aux` is virtual PURE in `LinearObject*` so no `lo->getCut_aux()` possible. And normally you shouldn't have to have multiple `getCut_aux` method. I will edit my post and you'll tell me if it's ok.

Comment: @Holt, well, it does look good =) but not really, since I NEED different implementations for `getCut_aux`, depending on the couple (Line-Line/Segment-Ray,etc.). When I think about it, a total different implementation (e.g where `Segment` and `Ray` inherit from `Line`) can make it work with one function, but then my whole question is irrelevant. Actually, in your settings, your answer can be further "optimized" by uniting `LinearObject` & `LinearObject_`. There is no need for them both to exist, I checked that.. but still, I return to the original question, with the last clarification.

Comment: @elad The `LinearObject_` is only there to avoid using `getCut` directly on a `LinearObject`, you can only use it on `Segment` and `Line`, it's what you asked in previous comment. Since you need differents function for each couple, this is a totally different question than your first in fact and you need to have different getCut_aux depending on the type of the argument as you do.

Comment: @Holt, to avoid using it on the "abstract" class, without defining another "abstract" class, you can also put it as private and use friend, like you actually did. And like I said, I tried to simplify the question for the sake of discussion, and it turned out to complicate it. Learned my lesson. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" solution for this is to do something like is to use virtual functions:

```
void f_aux (B * b)
{
  b->do_f_aux();
}
```

where you declare `do_f_aux` as

```
class B 
{
 ... 
 virtual void do_f_aux() { ... }; 
}
```

and of course implement the `do_f_aux` differently in `d1` and `d2`.

[This assumes you need `f_aux` as a standalone function - if you just need a function that does this, then just call the virtual function `f_aux`, and call it directly in the `f` as `bd1d2->f_aux()`]

Edit:

Casting objects in the way you describe is a "bad smell" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) - a symptom of "you're doing it wrong". It can almost always be avoided by using virtual functions.